# updating the state which is an array with the data coming from the parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some data coming from Parent as props and I need to create an option which is an array of objects with the help of the data coming from parent .
Here is the data coming from parent as props

```
 `data={
      option1: "First "
      option2: "Second"
      option3: "Third"
      option4: "Fourth"
    }`
```

What i need to create look something like this but in my state

```
    `const OPTIONS = [{
         label: 'First',
         value: '1'
       }, {
         label: 'Second',
         value: '2'
        }, {
         label: 'Third',
         value: '3'
        },{
        label:'Fourth',
        value:'4'
       }];`
```

I have my state inside array as

```
   `this.state={
             options:[]
      }`
```

What we really need to do is setState with the data coming from parent .In all the answers I don't see any setState any where .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

You can keep `First, Second and so on` in an array to get the value property in output.

So here the idea is to loop through the keys of `data` object and check the `indexOf` key if it is in values array we add 1 to it ( since the indexing of array start from 0 ) and if not we add `0`

```js
let data={ option1: "First",option2: "Second",option3: "Third",option4: "Fourth" }

let values = ['First','Second','Third', 'Fourth']

let op = Object.keys(data).map(e=>{
  let val = values.indexOf(data[e])
  return {
    label: e,
    value: val !==-1 ? val+1 : 0
  }
})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Where did you set the state ?

Comment: @DIXITKumar this example covers the conversion of data to desired format. now you can use `op` in `setState`  easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries`

```js
let data={ 
   option1: "First",
   option2: "Second",
   option3: "Third",
   option4: "Fourth" 
}

const options = Object.entries(data).map(arr=> ({
       label: arr[1],
       value: arr[0].replace( /^\D+/g, '')
   }))

console.log(options)
```

Comment: Where are you setting the state ?

Comment: It depends on you case. You can do it in constructor when component initialize or react lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

Hope your parent component looks like below:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data:  {
      "option1": "First ",
      "option2": "Second",
      "option3": "Third",
      "option4": "Fourth"
    }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and in Child you will get your data as this.props.data, the possible way to get this in state is `static getDerivedStateFromProps`, if you need to perform some side effects you can use `componentDidUpdate`

Below is the child component :

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      options: []
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        let { data } = nextProps;
        let options = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, curr) => {
            return [...acc, { label: data[curr], value: curr.replace( /^\D+/g, '') }]
    }, []);
        //or
        /*
        let options= Object.keys(nextProps.data).map((key, index) => ({label: nextProps.data[key], value: index}))};
        */
        return { options };
  }

  render() {
    return (
    this.state.options.map(item => <p key={item.value}>{item.label}</p>)
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ukehkv)

Comment: This is the worst use of `Array.map` Just return the object. `.map` returns an array by default

Comment: I don't see state being changed anywhere .

Comment: @DIXIT Kumar have you checked my answer ?